# GCS - split traffic (Between GAE and Storage) based on port

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

How does one configure Google Cloud Service to have a domain serve static files file storage (ie, html/css/js, via port 80), but send requests to the same domain on port 3000 go to App Engine, for a RESTFUL web app?

ie,

```
https://foo.com/   -- html/css/js served via Google Storage
https://foo.com/users:3000 -- ping app engine
```

Note: I do know how to host static files on Google Storage and use it as a website. What I need to know is how to configure requests to the same domain on port 3000 go to app engine instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, when serving static websites all the traffic goes to port 80. It will not be possible to route request depending on the port on the static website. A workaround here would be to have your main domain point to the static website, whereas you could have your subdomain pointing to the GAE application. This can be done by [mapping a custom subdomain](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains).